# Identity concerning Bessel functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, special-functions

I would like help showing the following is true:

$$\frac{d}{dx}[x^{-\alpha}J_{\alpha}(x)] = -x^{-\alpha}J_{\alpha+1}(x).$$

I can show $\frac{d}{dx}[x^{\alpha}J_{\alpha}(x)] = x^{\alpha}J_{\alpha-1}(x)$, however I am having a hard time extending this to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see the following recurrence relation between the Bessel function:

$$J_{n-1}(x)+J_{n+1}(x)=\displaystyle\frac{2n}{x} J_n(x)$$

$$J_{n-1}(x)-J_{n+1}(x)=2J'_n(x)$$

Adding these equations produces

$$J_{n-1}(x)=\displaystyle\frac{n}{x}J_n(x)+J'_n(x) $$

if you multiply by $x^n$ and play a little with the result you can get

$$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}[x^nJ_n(x)]=x^nJ_{n-1}(x)$$

in a similar way, if you subtract the equation, produces

$$J_{n+1}(x)=\displaystyle\frac{n}{x}J_n(x)-J'_n(x)$$

multiplying by $x^{-n}$ and playing with the equations, we obtain

$$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}[x^{-n}J_n(x)]=-x^{-n}J_{n+1}(x)$$

You can supply the details.